# Pegar somente o que foi alterado em um objeto

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Implementei uma função PATCH para atualizar os dados de um recurso, mas preciso pegar somente os dados atualizados de um objeto já carregado na tela para enviar na requisição.

Qual seria a forma mais eficiente de fazer isso? Dá pra usar o $watch ou é melhor evitar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Era bem mais simples do que eu pensava. Apenas criei uma função que compara dois objetos e retorna um objeto com as alterações.

```
function diffBetween(old, cur) {
    var updated = {};
    for (var prop in cur) {
        if (old[prop] != cur[prop]) {
            updated[prop] = cur[prop];
        }
    }
    return updated;
}
```